# Nginx proxy showing old content

Tags: nginx, caching, proxy, cdn, purge

I'm having some issues with our setup that contains:
Proxy -> CDN cache -> Origin.

It's setup so that if we update content on the origin, we purge the CDN cache, and with this I expect to see the update on the live site ( proxy ). But sometimes, around 20-30% of the time this does not reflect on the proxy, even if I see the **CDN is updated correctly**. And I cant wrap my head around why.

I've turned off the cache on the proxy.
Clearing the cache multiple times will eventually show the correct content for the times the proxy does not show the correct content after purge.

Responses for the different stages below.

*The CDN is from Microsoft azure by Verizon*

**Origin headers:**
[image: Origin response header]

**CDN headers:**
[image]

**Live headers:**
[image: Live response headers]

**Proxy config:**

```
server {
    server_name <DOMAIN>;
    location / {
      proxy_no_cache 1;
      proxy_cache_bypass 1; 
      proxy_redirect off;
      
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $http_host;
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_headers_hash_max_size 512;
      proxy_headers_hash_bucket_size 128;
      
      proxy_hide_header Cache-Control;
      add_header Cache-Control max-age=120; #Browser cache of 120s
      proxy_pass "https://<CDN-BASE-URL>$request_uri";
    }
}
```

Looking closer, it seems like the **Last-Modified** is a missmatch, could this be a cause?

Comment: When content changes, do you get the expected content if you curl your CDN from your proxy server (command line)? Also, may I ask why set the Cache-Control header on the CDN to max-age=31536000 but then hide this header on the proxy (using proxy_hide_header) and set it to max-age=120? Just trying to understand the use case. Thank you.

Comment: Yes, I do get the "updated" result going straight to the CDN url.
It's only the proxy that shows the incorrect page.

Why i'm setting the headers is that the headers is set individually on the server for different types of files and the CDN is respecting these headers,caching it on the CDN for that amount of time. But i'm overriding it cause i do not want clients browsers to cache for more than 120s.

Comment: OK. When you say you get the expected content when you go straight to CDN, you didn't confirm if that was by curl'ing the CDN from the proxy server. But it seems to be isolated to the proxy. I would try removing the "/" location block directives and re-adding one-by-one to see what introduces the issue.

Comment: I'm getting the correct result by visiting the CDN url directly eg without going through the proxy. But when visiting through the proxy i sometimes (not always, about 20% of the time) get old content, that is not present either on the CDN or the origin server. So it seems to get stuck on some caching or not revalidating correctly, although I thought i set the proxy up to never use cache.